# Marking an argument implicit inside a method

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a method that calls a few other methods that make use of an implicit of type `Foo`. I'd like to make f implicit inside Foo.  This is how I do it:

```
def myMethod(a: Int, f: Foo) = {
  implicit val implicitF = f;
  somethingThatNeedsFoo(a) 
}
```

I don't want to mark `f` implicit in the signature of myMethod since Foos are not implicit in the context that myMethod is being used. My question: is there a more idiomatic (or concise) way to achieve this effect than using a temporary variable?

Comment: In this simple example, it's probably easier to just pass `f` explicitly rather than using implicits—but I'm assuming your real code is complex enough to make the implicit worthwhile. In that case, I think your solution of declaring an `implicit val` inside the method is the best way to do it if you want to avoid declaring the parameter itself as implicit in the method signature.

Comment: @DaoWen You really should submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Aaron Novstrup - Yeah, looking at the other answers I probably should have. I'm still pretty new here, so I still have a hard time deciding what falls in the category of answer vs comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass implicit parameters explicitly, so even though there's no Foo in the implicit scope of the caller, the caller can just pass it explicitly.

As commented, you can use this same trick to pass the Foo to `somethingThatNeedsFoo`:

```
 def myMethod(a: Int, f: Foo) =
   somethingThatNeedsFoo(a)(f)
```

Answer (score 6):

I’ve never seen this being actually used but you can avoid binding the variable to a name. Using, of course, the underscore:

```
implicit val _ = f
```

I’d advise against this usage, though.

Comment: What's the reason to advise against this usage? I like that it avoids polluting the local namespace with an identifier that will never be used, and it's less "noise" in the code. Potential for confusing compiler errors?

Comment: I think it may be confusing because the underscore might also be perceived as ‘ignore/disable this implicit altogether’. (As in `import Predef.{any2stringadd => _, _}`.)